# Sort elements by relationship's column

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I'm creating search engine. It works reali simple. I have one var - $product and I use it to query building like this:
On the beginning I wrote

```
$product= Product::where('active', 1)->has('details');
```

And next step is extending this $query like this

```
if (strlen($request->name) > 3) {
    $product = $product->where('name', 'like', '%' .$request->name. '%');
}
```

I have a problem with sort results by price (price is into details table), I tryed this code

```
$product = $product->with([
    'details' => function($query) {
        $product->orderBy('price', 'asc');
    }
]);
```

My results doesn't sorted correctly. Why?

Comment: can you show your whole method??

Comment: which model has price ? Product or details

Comment: Controller method where you try to get info in db

Comment: Can you post the `details` relationship?

Answer (score 0):

You can't order by related model with eloquent relationships as they perform an additional query to get related results.

You need a join for that. Something like:

```
$product = $product
    ->join('details', 'details.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->select(['products.*', 'details.price'])
    ->orderBy('price');
```

The join I wrote is an educated guess on what your table columns/names might be since it's impossible to tell from your post. You might need to adjust them to work for you.

Answer (score 0):

To sort products based on related model (details) you can go with following approaches

Using [`sortBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-sortby) collection method

```
$products = $products->get()
                     ->sortBy(function($product) { 
                            return $product->details->price;
                      });
```

Or use join as stated by devk